# Sprite Kit Modifying Attribute of a Child SKShapeNode Does Not Work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a class named **Node**,

**Node** is a subclass of **SKNode**,

I have created and added a **SKShapeNode** object as a child in the *init* method of the **Node** object,

But when i try to modify this child object after adding it as a child, nothing happens.

```
@interface Node ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKShapeNode *circle;
@end

@implementation Node

- (id)initWithRadius:(float)radius{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _circle = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:radius];
        _circle.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _circle.name = @"c";
        [self addChild:_circle];
    }
    return self;
}

//1st type of handling child object
- (void)setHighlighted{

    NSLog(@"Called");
    SKShapeNode *circ = (SKShapeNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"/c"];
    circ.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
}
```

I also tried changing attribute of the property directly

```
- (void)setHighlighted{

   _circle.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
}
```

The *setHighlighted* method is being called for sure.

I even tried [_circle removeFromParent] and set position, alpha, isHidden attributes but nothing happens!!

What is the problem here?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

**There is no problem with the code above!**

Sorry the problem was: 
I have **NSArray *nodes**
I was populating nodes and as they are being created I stored them in a dummy **NSMutableArray *mutableNodesArray** at the same time I was adding them as a child to the scene; 
and after the loop finished, I **"copied"** objects from the **mutableNodesArray** to the **nodesArray**,

so when i was trying to do operations on a Node object stored inside the nodesArray, methods were being called but these methods did not belong to the Node objects added as a child...

My mistake...

Comment: you should be using the second method anyway since circle is global,  more efficient than the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
- (void)setupNodes{

    NSMutableArray *mutableNodesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Node *node = [[Node alloc] initWithRadius:nodeRadius];
        [self addChild:node];
        [mutableNodesArray addObject:node];
    }

    //Problematic Statement!
    _nodes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableNodesArray copyItems:YES];
}

- (void)operation{
    //This is not the node that is visible on the scene!
    [(Node*)[_nodes objectAtIndex:0] setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

And the solution is:

```
_nodes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableNodesArray];
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your problem is in the line:

```
SKShapeNode *circ = (SKShapeNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"/c"];
```

that could be:

```
SKShapeNode *circ = (SKShapeNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"//c"];
```

Differences according to [API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74) reference:

**/** :

> When placed at the start of the search string, this indicates that
>   the search should be performed on the tree’s root node. When placed
>   anywhere but the start of the search string, this indicates that the
>   search should move to the node’s children.

**//** :

> When placed at the start
>   of the search string, this specifies that the search should begin at
>   the root node and be performed recursively across the entire node
>   tree. Otherwise, it performs a recursive search from its current
>   position.

You could try to put also a breakpoint to the line below and check to the debug console the circ properties with `po circ.debugDescription` :

(breakpoint to the line:)
-> `circ.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];`

You could try also to use a `customActionWithDuration`:

```
SKAction* circleColor = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:0.5f actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime)
{
    circ.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
    NSLog(@"changed to red");
}];
[circ runAction:circleColor];
```

Comment: Unfortunately @"//c" did not solve the problem, I have looked the debug description with /c and and also with //c, the objects are valid. The odd thing is, when i do the operation in the original question with SKSpriteNode child object, there is no problem.(with only difference: i am sending sprite node objects from the scene object not constructing in the init method of the Node class) but SKShapeNode child seems like static ( like i need to call sth like setNeedsDisplay kind of message :) cannot even remove it from the parent.

Comment: Thanks, I will not be able to try your suggestion until tomorrow but i think SKAction approach will solve the problem by intuition so I am marking it as correct answer. I can understand why it won't work to change attributes related to core graphics, but really wonder why i cannot change the position etc (matrix/transformation related attributes) and even cannot remove from parent directly without using SKAction, any idea?

Comment: Much of this work depend by the exact moment you call these changes, didMoveToView should be the correct method.Also instead of SKSpriteNode, SKShapeNode don't have a direct color property. so the getter setter method invoked for "color" and called by other actions doesn't exist in SKShapeNode. It's worth a try to debug inside didFinishUpdate() to see if fillColor change his value..it's just an idea..

Comment: Unfortunately SKAction method did not solve the problem. It is very weird, after adding a SKShapeNode as a child of a SKNode, i cannot do any operation with it afterwards...

Comment: Check my edited question. This is my first question on Stack Overflow should i delete the question?

Comment: @user3390500. Nope,  it is a good question,  be sure to answer yourself.  People in the future will see it and get that aha! or that was dumb of me momment and you will have helped them